# Apache Airflow: Share a pool between different instances?

Tags: airflow

I'm running different instances of airflow next to each other (one per environment - staging and production for example).

I have a number of limited resources, for which i use pools.
I would like to know if there is a way to "share a pool" between different airflow instances (like a pool-allocator that uses the API of the remote instance on one end for example).

I'm not looking for remarks / suggestions on how to combine different environments in one airflow, please. Just answers relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

A pool only exists within one Airflow instance, there is no concept of "cross-Airflow pools".

It's a good practice to keep such environments isolated from each other. You don't want faulty code in a development environment to have an impact on a production environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm indeed aware that there is no "in the box" solution for this. I am/was hoping there was some out of the box one though.